# Windows Batch scripting to copy files from last week

Tags: batch-file, scripting, copy

I'm trying to automatically copy 5 .xlsx files from the server to my desktop. I will do this every Monday. The files are from previous week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)

My date scripting is not working. Can someone help me?

```
C:\Users\jgi>forfiles /P C:\Users\jgi\Documents /S /D +(today'date - 7 days)
```

ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirements, you will need something like this:

```
@echo off

forfiles /P C:\Users\jgi\Documents /S /M *.xlsx /D -8 /C "cmd /c copy @file D:\Desktop\"
```

- `/P` option specifies the directory to search for the files.
- `/S` is used to say `forfiles` to search files in all subdirectories of location specified in `/P`.
- `/M` specifies which files should be processed.
- `/D` Selects files with a last modified date greater than or equal to `(+)`, or less than or equal to `(-)`.
- `/C` specifies command to be run for each file found.

  - `cmd /c` tells system to open a new `cmd` which will will carry out the command specified by string and then it will terminate.
  - Now, `copy` `@file` (`forfiles` variable; returns the name of the file) to a custom destination.